# How do I save data created in a form in Access 2003 when I reference other tables?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, save

I'm not sure how to fix this issue, but when I utilize combo boxes on my form which selects data from multiple tables I'm not able to save any of the data selected.

I tried to use the Bound form utility but it only asked me to "Enter Parameter Value".  I took out the "Bound" portion of the code and the combo box works fine.

I have a nice little save button, but it doesn't actually save anywhere.

I tried using a query, but that didn't fix it either unless, of course, I didn't do the query correctly.

Here is the "Row Source" information...

`SELECT SubArea.SubAreaID, SubArea.SubAreaName, SubArea.ProductName FROM SubArea WHERE (((SubArea.ProductName)=Forms![Combo Form]!Product));`

Do I need to put something in VBA or perhaps a Macro to have all the data selected to actually save into a table?  HELP!

Comment: This question is way to disorganized to be answerable. Explain what your form is, i.e., what data it displays. Explain what the combo box is for and where it's drawing its data from. Then we'd have a chance of explaining what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

For the Bound Form

Open the form in design mode, right click on the combo box and go to properties. Check out if it is actually bound to something in the **Control Source** field.

Comment: It would appear that nothing is in the Control Source field.  Do I need to add something there like the Table I want the Data saved in or where the actual data is coming from?

Comment: The Control source field should contain the name of the field that you want the data to be saved in.